# Bootstrap CSS Navbar Overflow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have an issue when the navbar components all have really long texts.
What happens is that the navbar expands vertically and overlaps with site content.

I want the navbar not to expand and instead the content's overflow to be hidden.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>    
    <p class="navbar-brand">Brand Title</p>
  </div>  
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Looooooooonnnnnngggg Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Longggggggggggggggggggg Text</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#about">Loooong Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">LongText</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#about">Reallyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy  Looooooooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnngggg Text</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you show the exact problem in a jsfiddle??
what I can say from what I understood here is to just use the css overflow:hidden;

Comment: you don't need to type <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> many times ... lolz

Comment: Have you tried `overflow: hidden;` or `word-break: break-word;`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a208zvyz/ is the fiddle. I want the text to be hidden, so that the navbar doesnt expand vertically.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by using a fix width for the `a` tags.

```
ul li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100px;
}
```

The result: http://jsfiddle.net/j47cn28u/

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    nav.navbar { 
        max-height: 60px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/a208zvyz/3/)**